# Customize syntax highlighting RStudio

Tags: rstudio, syntax-highlighting

I'm wondering if it is possible to highlight `---` in the Visual Editor of RStudio so that `---` can easily catch my attention. I use `---` a lot to separate slides. Can I do this by changing options?